# Programmatically Get Conda3 Build Hash

Tags: travis-ci, conda

I am trying to use Travis to build a package (which is working) and then upload that package to Anaconda cloud.  The issue that I am having is with getting the 'new' package hash.  The build environment variable `PKG_HASH` contains the string that I am trying to access ([docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/environment-variables.html)).

The upload line is: `anaconda -t $CONDA_UPLOAD_TOKEN upload -u $USER $CONDA_BLD_PATH/$OS/$PKG_NAME-$VERSION-h$PKG_HASH_0.tar.bz2 --force`.

Does anyone know how to programmatically get $PKG_HASH after the build has occurred?  This way the package can get pushed to anaconda cloud.

Comment: Good question, +1. However, are you building packages that you don't want to upload? Why not just use a wildcard instead of directly specifying everything?